# "Wie alt das(s) er ist"

Tags: dialect

Jemand fragte mich vor Kurzem:

> Und, haben Sie geschaut, wie alt das(s) er ist?

Der Sprecher hat »Honoratiorenschwäbisch« gesprochen, ich kannte das allerdings von einer deutlich als solche erkennbaren Pfälzerin/Kölnerin. Ich habe es auch nie in süddeutschen Dialekten gehört.

Kann jemand was Näheres dazu sagen? Hat das eine Bezeichnung? (Ich denke übrigens spontan an Topikalisierung.)

Comment: [Diese Diss](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/fileadmin/prag/AusVar/Deutsch_in_Russland/Textsammlung.pdf) erwähnt das Phänomen (ab S. 18 unten) in Bezug auf einen rheinfränkischen Dialekt von Russlanddeutschen. Ich hab grad keine Zeit, weiter zu googlen, aber vielleicht hilft es Dir.

Comment: Das ist ein auch in Österreich vebreiteter (umgangssprachlicher) Ausdruck.

Comment: Vielleicht kann mir jemand erklären, um was es in dieser Frage geht. Was soll "das(s)" bedeuten? Doppel-S ist definitiv falsch, es sei denn es soll "das's", sprich "das es", sein. Für mich ist der Satz aber so oder so eine reine Katastrophe. Soll der Satz irgendeine Aussage haben? Eine Kölnerin sagt das mit Sicherheit nicht.

Comment: Ach und... Für *was* wird hier eine Bezeichung gesucht? Zu *was* soll man hier näheres sagen?

Comment: @Em1: Wohl mehr als offensichtlich für dieses "das(s)" bzw. die Konstruktion, die im Standarddeutschen so nicht verwendet werden kann, in manchen Dialekten hingegen schon.

Comment: Kenne ich auch im (Ober)bairischen

Comment: @Georg Ja, gehört alles zur [Dialektgruppe Bairisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairisch): „_die südöstliche Dialektgruppe im deutschen Sprachraum_“.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Es ist auf jeden Fall *dass* gemeint. *Das* passt dort überhaupt nicht hin, weder als Artikel noch als Relativ- oder Demonstrativpronomen.

In [*Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm, Leipzig 1854-1961*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=dasz), fand ich Verwendungen von *dass*, vormals *dasz*, die heutzutage niemand mehr so gebrauchen würde und die durch Weglassen, wie im Beispiel in der Frage auch, die Sätze auch für heutige Ohren "normal" klingen lassen:

*„ich arbeitete bis <s>zu der zeit dasz</s> er kam. bis <s>dahin dasz</s> ich abreise, werde ich beschäftigt sein. während <s>dasz</s> wir bei tische saszen, brach ein gewitter aus.“*

*„indessen[heute eher: während] <s>dasz</s> er schlief, ward sein zimmer ausgeschmückt. seit <s>dasz</s> er weg ist, habe ich keinen ruhigen augenblick gehabt.“*

*„bis <s>dasz</s> er wiederkehrt, müssen wir warten.“*

*„bevor <s>dasz</s> er kam“*

Die bisher Genannten ordne ich dem zu, was im [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dass) als *[8] temporale Subjunktion* bezeichnet wird.

*„je übermütiger <s>dasz</s> er wird“*

Mit diesem Letzten wird es etwas interessanter. Da steht auch ein Adjektiv – wenn auch im Komparativ – davor und ich finde dazu im Wiktionary keine Entsprechung. Ich kann mir dazu gut Folgendes (Achtung! Privatthese!) vorstellen:

Von *„je älter dass er wird“* ist es nicht weit zu *„wie alt dass er ist“*.

Etwas, das genau dem Beispel von oben entspricht, konnte ich leider (bislang) nicht finden.

Im entsprechenden Abschnitt der [Textsammlung](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/fileadmin/prag/AusVar/Deutsch_in_Russland/Textsammlung.pdf), die [Matthias](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9091/matthias) nennt, geht es um *abhängige prädikative Konstruktionen* (APK). Das dortige *„wie viel Geld dass du kriegst“* im Vergleich zu *„wie alt dass du bist“* sieht recht vielversprechend für eine Bezeichnung aus: *„APK, die durch Interrogativpronomen in Verbindung mit der Konjunktion [tas] = „dass“ eingeleitet werden“*.

Falls jemand Genaueres erfragen möchte: [Die Übersetzerin](http://www.musikundkunstschule-nw.de/Elenakaul.html) ist an der *Musik und Kunstschule Neustadt* [sic, ohne Ergänzungsstrich, und das mit einer Sprachwissenschafterin ;-] zu finden.

[Topikalisierung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topikalisierung) sehe ich hier keine.

[painfulenglishs](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/10760/painfulenglish) Kommentar, dass das *„ein auch in Österreich verbreiteter (umgangssprachlicher) Ausdruck“* ist, unterstütze ich.

Comment: Auch heute kennt/sagt man noch: "Bis _dass_ der Tod euch scheide(t)"

Answer (score 1):

Diesen Ausdruck kenne ich auch, aus dem Rheinland/Niederrhein und konkret auch aus Köln.
Sprachlich erkläre ich ihn mir so: Es ist eine Vermischung aus einem indirekten Fragesatz und einem Inhaltssatz/dass-Satz, die beide abhängig von Wörtern wie "glauben", "sagen", "denken" sind.

Answer (score -1):

Ich würde dieses "das" in manchen Dialekten als ein demonstratives "das" erklären:

Hast du das (das Folgende) nachgeschaut: Wie alt er ist?

Wenn die beiden Sätze verbunden werden, wandert das "das" einfach in den zweiten Teil. Und jetzt kann man wirklich fragen, ist es ein "das" oder ein "dass" und kommt aus dem Grübeln nicht mehr raus. Man kriegt eher einen Knoten ins Gehirn. Deswegen würde ich sagen, man kann wohl beide Deutungen in Betracht ziehen.

Im Grunde ist es auch egal, denn "dass" in "Ich weiß, dass er nicht kommt" ist ja eigentlich nichts anderes als:

Ich weiß das (das Folgende): Er kommt nicht.

Aber ich würde die Schreibung dass vorziehen, einfach um zu zeigen, dass es nicht der Artikel oder das Pronomen "das" ist. Eher ein überflüssiges Füllwort, das ein Überbleibsel darstellt, das noch auf die historische Entstehung dieser Konstruktion hinweist.